# Windows batch: replace strings in a file case sensitively

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've spent a lot of time writing a script to generate new files using a "template" (coding env.) project.

While on Unix the shell script is laughably easy I spent days doing the same on Windows...

My current batch file does almost everything I need, except that the string replacement is case-insensitive... That is, it replaces "emptyproject" with "EMPTYPROJECT", being the first statement...

Code:

```
@echo off & setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set argc=0
for %%x in (%*) do set /A argc+=1

if /I "%argc%" EQU "0" (
 echo Usage: %0 PROJECT_NAME >&2
 exit /B 1
)

set curr_dir=%~dp0
set project_name=%1
set project_name_lower=%1
set project_name_upper=%1
set project_file="vstudio\projects\%project_name%.vcxproj"
set project_filters="vstudio\projects\%project_name%.vcxproj.filters"

call :toupper project_name_upper
call :tolower project_name_lower

if not exist %project_file% (
 copy /y "vstudio\projects\EmptyProject.vcxproj" %project_file% >nul
 copy /y "vstudio\projects\EmptyProject.vcxproj.filters" %project_filters% >nul
)

set project_source_dir=..\projects\source\%project_name_lower%

if not exist %project_source_dir% (
 mkdir %project_source_dir%

 call :copy_and_replace_strings "..\projects\source\emptyproject\main.cpp" "%project_source_dir%\main.cpp" %project_name% %project_name_lower% %project_name_upper%
 call :copy_and_replace_strings "..\projects\source\emptyproject\emptyproject.h" "%project_source_dir%\%project_name_lower%.h" %project_name% %project_name_lower% %project_name_upper%
 call :copy_and_replace_strings "..\projects\source\emptyproject\emptyproject_main.cpp" "%project_source_dir%\%project_name_lower%_main.cpp" %project_name% %project_name_lower% %project_name_upper%
 call :copy_and_replace_strings "..\projects\source\emptyproject\emptyproject_eventhandlers.cpp" "%project_source_dir%\%project_name_lower%_eventhandlers.cpp" %project_name% %project_name_lower% %project_name_upper%
)

endlocal
goto :EOF

REM functions
:toupper
 for %%L IN (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) DO SET %1=!%1:%%L=%%L!
 goto :EOF

:tolower
 for %%L IN (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) DO SET %1=!%1:%%L=%%L!
 goto :EOF

:copy_and_replace_strings <source_file> <target_file> <name> <lower> <upper>
 for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%a in ('find /n /v "" ^< %1') do (
  set token1=%%a
  set token2=%%b

  if defined token2 (
REM not case sensitive
   set token2=!token2:EMPTYPROJECT=%5!
   set token2=!token2:EmptyProject=%3!
   set token2=!token2:emptyproject=%4!
   echo !token2!>>%2
  ) else (
   echo[>>%2
  )
 )
 goto :EOF
```

I read a lot about this on this forum, but couldn't find a suitable solution. Could someone help me please?

Comment: So you want to replace strings with case sensitive strings?

Comment: I would like to replace case sensitive strings (like EmptyProject) with another string (like MyNewProject or mynewPROJECT or basically anything). The problem is that the 'set' command itself is case-insensitive.

Comment: aaah ok. well then my answer will not help at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR %%o IN (EMPTYPROJECT EmptyProject emptyproject EmPtYpRoJeCt) DO (
 SET "token2=A line containing %%o in it"
 CALL :magic
 ECHO !token2! -^> !result!
)

GOTO :EOF

:magic
SET "result=!token2!"
ECHO !token2!|FINDSTR "EMPTYPROJECT" >NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 set "result=!token2:EMPTYPROJECT=capiTaLs!"
ECHO !token2!|FINDSTR "EmptyProject" >NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 set "result=!token2:EMPTYPROJECT=Mixed!"
ECHO !token2!|FINDSTR "emptyproject" >NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 set "result=!token2:EMPTYPROJECT=lower!"
GOTO :eof
```

Perhaps this will be of assistance.

Comment: thanks, this helped I just had to put !token! into quotes like

    echo "!token2!"|findstr EMPTYPROJECT >nul

etc.

Answer (score 0):

To be rather honest, your quickest method to keep it pure batch is to trick the system and use `powershell` in the background.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "input=i want this upper case"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`powershell "\"%input%\".toUpper()"`) do set "lower=%%~a"

set "input=I WANT THIS LOWER CASE"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`powershell "\"%input%\".toLower()"`) do set "upper=%%~a"
echo !lower!
echo !upper!
```

**RESULT**

> I WANT THIS UPPER CASE
>
> i want this lower case